# Is Red Gate SQL Test tSQLt version the same as in GitHub?

Tags: redgate, tsqlt

**Part 1 of my question is:**
I'm trying to find the benefits in buying Red Gate SQL Test VS simply using the free tSQLt on its own.
I already saw 2 similar questions that were answered by Red Gate who basically said that the UI to organize the tests is the main benefit.

I was also thinking that maybe since SQL Test is a paid tool, its tSQLt version will be better or with good maintenance/features but then I saw this post (https://forum.red-gate.com/discussion/18049/sql-test-is-over-a-year-behind-tsqlt) in the Red Gate forum where a user was complaining that the tSQLt version of SQL Test was 2 versions behind the tSQLt open-source code...so even that is not an advantage, and it seems like using the SQL Test might be even a disadvantage on this aspect of having the latest version.

Does anyone know of any reason why to buy SQL Test tool?
Is there anyone that uses tSQLt on its own in an environment where there are many developers that might want to add unit tests?

**Part 2 of my question is:**
After stating the above, I'm considering using the open-source tSQLt on its own.
What I am thinking of doing is -

1. when a developer creates a DB replica in order to develop SQL code on it, that replica will already have tSQLt on it.
2. the developer will create his test SPs and then push them into the repository under a new "tests" folder (that will not be deployed as part of the version)
3. when he will create a PR to add his code, a new task that we will create in the pipeline, will deploy the committed tests that are in "tests" folder into the DB that we already raise for the SQL code to run on (that DB will already have tSQLt on it and instead of running only the code from the "product" folder, we will also run the code from "tests" folder)
4. the task will also call tSQLt.RunAll

(I'm not a DevOps specialist but this is basically the plan and of course our DevOps will implement and make sure that the tests results will be diaplayed clearly using SP tSQLt.XmlResultFormatter)

what do you think?
did anyone do something similar?
I'll appreciate any help
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part one: I asked Redgate to write SQL Test to get the point and click integration other unit testing frameworks have in their respective gui(s).  Besides the interface, sql test does not add anything to tSQLt. (Though, it integrates with sql cover, which is a separate project. ) if you are looking for enterprise support for tSQLt, talk to me. I’m in the process of creating an offer along that line.

Part two: that is a good basic outline for a CI pipeline. I would consider adding a step to recreate the database from scratch instead of deploying the changes to an existing DB. That way you don’t need to worry about things getting messed up in your DB and then impacting the test run negatively.

Comment: Thank you very much, Sebastian Meine, for your quick response.
We are using Docker with a clean baseline DB, I just didn't want to complicate my description so I used a more general/basic description.

Did you have a chance to use tSQLt and deploy the tests during your work in the way I described?
Do you know of a place that has "best practices" info about what is the correct way to test SQL code? (for example if I have an SP that does something - what should be the basic tests scenarios I should write in order to test it)
Thanks

Comment: @Ronit, yes, I have used tSQLt in a way similar to what you describe and I have helped many to do the same in their work. There are a few hundred tests in the tSQLt project itself that you can look at.

Comment: tests in tSQLt repository: https://github.com/tSQLt-org/tSQLt/tree/main/Tests

Comment: tSQLt CI Pipeline example run: https://sqlity.visualstudio.com/tSQLt%20CI/_build/results?buildId=6275&view=ms.vss-test-web.build-test-results-tab

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on an open source project called testQL which sets up everything you need for testing SQL through Github actions. It works well for TSQL (among others). Its easy to install/use and abstracts away most of the complexity. Hopefully that helps!
https://github.com/ThugPigeon653/testQL-source.git